# Why two objects are converted to the same string?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am not able to understand why the output for the below code is "value". Why foo and bar is converted to the same string?

```js
let foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
object[foo] = 'value'
console.log(object[bar])
```

Comment: Look at `foo.toString()` and `bar.toString()`.

Comment: Object keys are strings, and objects cast to strings are `[object Object]`